# WebRTC for Android (newbe)

Tags: android, webrtc

I am trying to build a WebRTC Android app in order to exchange data between two (or more) android handsets.

However, I cannot work out from where I should start.

should I start by :

- building a TURN & STUN signaling servers, or ...
- creating the Android-app interface through which I should use GetUserMedia, or ...
- using RTCPeerConnection for candidates discovery?

I kindly asking for some tutorials. I am really confused about how to use WebRTC APIs. I am looking for a practical example of how to integrate WebRTC functionality in an android app. Thank you.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @PrerakSola: **Sorry for going out off topic. Shoudl I delete the question ?**.  I am just very very confused. All I am looking for is start point. That is it. I read a lot but there is no solid explanation or actual guidance on how to use WebRTC APIs. I just need any any any start point for WebRTC for android

Comment: @PrerakSola: All I did is that I create user interface. But I cannot even move from there !!

Comment: Check out this Android app AppRTCDemo https://github.com/njovy/AppRTCDemo and server https://github.com/webrtc/apprtc